# Sorting a matrix arbitrarily by columns

Tags: python, sorting, list-comprehension

I have a matrix like:

```
[[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5],
 [4,1,3,6,2],
 [9,4,1,3,6]]
```

I want to reorder the matrix by columns arbitrarily like:

```
[[col3,col1,col5,col4,col2],
 [3,4,2,6,1],
 [1,9,6,3,4]]
```

I know that if that would be one row, I could create an order list like `order_list = [2,0,4,3,1]` and then use list comprehension `ordered_list = [old_list[i] for i in order_list]` but here I couldn't come up with a way to create a nested comprehension where I do this operation for each row.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using numpy's fancy indexing.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[4,1,3,6,2], [9,4,1,3,6]])                                                                                           
>>> cols = [2,0,4,3,1]                                                                                                                 
>>> a.T[cols].T                                                                                                                        
>>> 
array([[3, 4, 2, 6, 1],
       [1, 9, 6, 3, 4]])
```

Details:

```
>>> a
array([[4, 1, 3, 6, 2],
       [9, 4, 1, 3, 6]])
>>> a.T
array([[4, 9],
       [1, 4],
       [3, 1],
       [6, 3],
       [2, 6]])
>>> a.T[cols]
array([[3, 1],
       [4, 9],
       [2, 6],
       [6, 3],
       [1, 4]])
>>> a.T[cols].T
array([[3, 4, 2, 6, 1],
       [1, 9, 6, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The actual matrix that I am working is much bigger than the example. I have 10 columns and 800 rows + 1 header row. After getting the transpose of the array, I try to do the `a.T[cols]` part but it says "index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9"

Comment: @ykesen the last index for an axis with size 9 is 8, so the error you are getting is expected.

Answer (score 2):

If list comprehesion is what you must do.

Having a list

```
l=[[2,0,1],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Using some list slicing you can do

```
>>> [[x[i] for i in l[0]] for x in l[1:]]
[[6, 4, 5], [9, 7, 8]]
```

If you want the whole array back you can do

```
>>> [l[0]]+[ [x[i] for i in l[0]] for x in l[1:]]
[[2, 0, 1], [6, 4, 5], [9, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was actually trying to sort the lists. Not the elements inside of the sublists. So in the main list, I want to sort the sublists according to the first elements.